# unicorn is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, unicorn, digital-ocean

While trying to deploy on digital ocean (Ubuntu, Ruby on Rails) with capistrano, nginx and unicorn, I'm getting this error:

```
DEBUG[fae8c972]     /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:252:in `block in replace_gem'
DEBUG[fae8c972]     :
DEBUG[fae8c972]     unicorn is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.
DEBUG[fae8c972]      (
DEBUG[fae8c972]     Gem::LoadError
DEBUG[fae8c972]     )
DEBUG[fae8c972]         from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/unicorn:22:in `<main>'
cap aborted!
```

unicorn gem is present in gemfile and gemfile.lock

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Update - Just found that my server is picking older version of Gemfile (which doesn't have unicorn listed in it). Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Is unicorn registered in your Gemfile?

Comment: And have you run ``bundle install`` on your digital ocean machine ?

Comment: yes, it is present in gemfile and gemfile.lock

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/yz8cha this seems to be a good article about DO, Unicorn and Capistrano

Comment: tried running bundle install on current folder of my project on digital ocean, but still failing with same error.

Answer (score 0):

Deployment was happening from master branch by default.

Adding this line to deploy.rb solved the issue:
set :branch, 'develop'